# Data input to debugger before hitting the breakpoint

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, windbg

I have an application running on target machine and trying to debug it from my PC using WinDbg. Now I would like to input some value to WinDbg before hitting the conditional breakpoint and the same shall be passed in as an argument to the conditional break point as soon as it is hit.

My ultimate aim is that I do not want WinDbg waiting for input for more than a second when the breakpoint is hit. As you all know, WinDbg freezes all threads when the breakpoint is hit, hence I'm getting lot timer elapse issue after continue (using `g`).

I know that I can use a file (by putting desired data in) and parse it as soon as the break point is hit. But I want the user to enter desired data (maximum 5) before the breakpoint hits and pass in that data to application local when conditional break point is hit.

I use the following conditional breakpoint `bp FileName.cpp:341 "j (1) '.echo \"Breakpoint hit, condition\";ed dwRand 12;gc'; 'gc'"`

Actually I would like to get `dwRand` value before the breakpoint hits, and upon breakpoint hit update the conditional breakpoint as `ed dwRand <VALUE>`.

Comment: It is not clear if the input you need should be coming from the user of the application of from the person operating the debugger?

Comment: @AlexanderBalabin I would like to get it from person who is operating the debugger. Actually I would like to control output of my application based on value of a local variable dwRand which is given through ed dwRand.

Comment: Still not 100% sure I understand the question but if you'd like to enter new value for dwRand _when breakpoint is hit_ then just omit the value from the `ed` command and the debugger will prompt for it. I do not think there is a way to do it _before_ the breakpoint is hit.

Comment: How is this related to remote debugging, VS2013 and XDebug? Please remove tags which are not relevant to the question.

Comment: @ Alexander Balabin Yes you are right, I would like to get the values before the breakpoint is hit. Somehow I manage to do that using `.cmdtree CMDTREE.txt` using the link [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/debuggingtoolbox/archive/2008/09/17/special-command-execute-commands-from-a-customized-user-interface-with-cmdtree.aspx). But still I'm not convinced and would like to have better user interface for getting input from the person who is operating the debugger.

Comment: The content of the CMDTREE.TXT                                                   `windbg ANSI Command Tree 1.0
title {"Common Commands"}
body
{"Common Commands"}
 {"BreakPoint"}
  {"Set only Break Point"} {"bp `PlatformManager.cpp:341`"}
  {"Set Conditional Break Point"} {"bp \`PlatformManager.cpp:341\` "j (1) '.echo \"Breakpoint hit\";ed dwRand 10'; 'gc'""}`

Answer (score 0):

WinDbg does not freeze threads on its own, it suspends them, which is a difference (see `.hh freeze` for details). If all your timers are on other threads, you can resume all of those threads:

```
0:000> r $t0 = @$tid
0:000> ~*e .if (@$t0 != $tid) {~~[$tid]m} .else { .echo "current thread" }
current thread
0:000> ~
.  0  Id: 1624.f6c Suspend: 1 Teb: 7efdd000 Unfrozen
   1  Id: 1624.180c Suspend: 0 Teb: 7efda000 Unfrozen
   2  Id: 1624.864 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7efd7000 Unfrozen
   3  Id: 1624.1d4c Suspend: 0 Teb: 7efaf000 Unfrozen
   4  Id: 1624.14b0 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7efac000 Unfrozen
   5  Id: 1624.1e54 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7efa9000 Unfrozen
   6  Id: 1624.774 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7efa6000 Unfrozen
   7  Id: 1624.1810 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7efa0000 Unfrozen
```

Like this, only the current thread (`0`) remains suspended (`Suspend: 1`) until you finished modifying memory. All other threads are running (`Suspend: 0`).

Comment: I tried this but this command takes longer time than one second hence I'm not able to achieve what I needed. I think that the `~~[$tid]m` and `.if(@$td0 != $tid)` consumes little more time. Do I miss something else?

Comment: I noticed that despite thread's Suspend state is 0 (**Suspend: 0**) the threads are not running but still suspended and waiting for `g` to continue. There are totally 26 threads running in my application.

Comment: @Panch: I thought it would be fast enough to resume all threads, but I haven't tested the performance. I'll investigate in the fact that the threads do not resume.

Comment: I found this statement _In any event, threads that belong to the target process never execute when the debugger has broken into the target. The suspend count of a thread affects the thread's behavior only when the debugger executes the process or detaches. The frozen status affects the thread's behavior only when the debugger executes the process._ From this I understand that the suspend count take effect only when debugger is executing the target. So the threads wont be running when a breakpoint is hit despite its suspend count is 0.

Comment: @Panch: thanks for researching the details. I didn't know that. This somehow renders my answer invalid.

Answer (score 0):

#### :\>ls -l

```
-rw-rw-rw-  1 Admin 0 128 2015-07-13 19:17 hitchange.cpp
```

#### :\>cat hitchange.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void main (void) {
  for (int i =0; i< 10; i++){
    printf("%08x\n",rand());
  }
}
```

#### :\>..\compile.bat

```
:\>cl /Zi /EHsc /nologo /W4 /analyze *.cpp /link /RELEASE
hitchange.cpp
```

#### :\>hitchange.exe

```
00000029
00004823
000018be
00006784
00004ae1
00003d6c
00002cd6
000072ae
00006952
00005f90
```

#### :\>cdb -c "bp hitchange!printf \"r $t0 =poi(@esp+8);.printf \\\"actual rand valu
e @ [esp+8] = %08x\\n\\\",@$t0 ;ed @esp+8 f001;gc;\";g;q" hitchange.exe

```
0:000> cdb: Reading initial command 'bp hitchange!printf "r $t0 =poi(@esp+8);.pr
intf \"actual rand value @ [esp+8] = %08x\\n\",@$t0 ;ed @esp+8 f001;gc;";g;q'

actual rand value @ [esp+8] = 00000029
0000f001
actual rand value @ [esp+8] = 00004823
0000f001
actual rand value @ [esp+8] = 000018be
0000f001
actual rand value @ [esp+8] = 00006784
0000f001
actual rand value @ [esp+8] = 00004ae1
0000f001
actual rand value @ [esp+8] = 00003d6c
0000f001
actual rand value @ [esp+8] = 00002cd6
0000f001
actual rand value @ [esp+8] = 000072ae
```

Comment: I get _Syntax_ _error_ _at_ if I use this command `cdb -c "bp Platform!PlatformManager::RqRandomNumber \"r $t0=poi(@esp+8);.printf\\\"actual rand value @[esp+8]=%08x\\n\\\",@$t0;ed @esp+8 f001;gc;\";g;q" Platform.exe`.

Comment: you are not supposed to copy the command verbatim it is just an example first of all try copying the required variable to pseudo register and printing it  in my case above poi(esp+8) was the variable in your case it might be [eax + 48 +ecx]  set a breakpoint like bp address " r $t0 = <your var> ; ? @$t0" and see if it prints the right value if you got the right value build upon it using the example posted DO NOT COPY VARBATIM EACH SITUATION HAS ITS OWN VARIABLE ESP+8 is not MAGIC

Comment: I understand that I should not have copied the command section as it is and in my case it is rsp+32. But the result is somewhat similar to `bp FileName.cpp:341 "j (1) '.echo \"Breakpoint hit, condition\";ed dwRand 12;gc'; 'gc'"` where the dwRand is set to 12 whenever the breakpoint is hit.

Comment: sorry i cant make any sense out of your comment  reiterating again set a bp on the address required (use assembly mode "your syntax shows you are using src mode and in src mode one line can mean n numbers of assembly lines )  viz bp 401084 when you are satisfied you got hit at the right place add a simple condition to your breakpoint viz bp 401084 " r $t0 = poi(<reg + offset>) ; ? @$t0"  run a few times to let the breakpoint hit and ensure your Pseudo Register is printed right every time if it is right then use the pseudo register to add complexities to your condition hope i made it clear

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it. Actually I used the command `cdb -c "bp `PlatformManager.cpp:341` \"r $t0=poi(@rsp+32);.printf\\\"actual rand value @[rsp+32]=%08x\\n\\\",@$t0;ed @esp+32 10;gc;\";g;q" Platform.exe`. Please note that in my case the variable is rsp+32. As per this whenever the breakpoint is hit, the variable is updated with value 10. So debugger wont wait for input and continue execution immediately after modifying the value of variable.

Comment: Actually my original intention was that I would like to modify the outcome of a game play and the game play requires some X random numbers to award something. Hence by controlling these random numbers I want to predetermine my game play outcome. So I want to hack the portion of my code where the random number is obtained from rng. But breaking the game execution causes some of my devices time out and eventually triggers time out errors. This affects my normal game flow.

Comment: So initially I tried for the suggestion provided by Thomas (i.e. resuming all threads but the still suspending the one which broke the execution) but the WinDbg did not support that. So to be clear that I'm able to conditional break my game's execution. Now I have decided to disable the devices which causes the timeout, hence now I'm able to hack the random numbers using the method described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31533512/can-windbg-connect-to-stdin-of-a-debuggee-which-is-running-remotely/31556349#31556349) by you but I use tcp instead of pipe.