# can WinDbg connect to stdin of a debuggee which is running remotely

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, windbg

I'm having a hard time to control my application using WinDbg, I had already posted my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31378816/data-input-to-debugger-before-hitting-the-breakpoint/31385486?noredirect=1#comment51023520_31385486) and left that approach as I'm not able figure out a way on how to achieve that.
Now I'm working on the approach that after breakpoint is hit, I would like to branch out my application execution and prompt input from user who is running the debugger.

```
DWORD dwRand = 0;
volatile bool bDebug = false;
if (!bDebug)
{
    dwRand = Rand(minValue, maxValue);
}
else
{
    cout << "\n Enter dwRand: ";
    cin >> dwRand;
}
return dwRand;
```

So my idea is to set the `bDebug` and get the input from user so I can continue other threads execution and waiting for user input.
I found these links[1](http://webstersprodigy.net/2012/08/17/redirecting-stdin-on-windbg/)  [2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/102351)   [3](http://w3facility.org/question/how-to-tell-windbg-to-connect-stdin-of-a-debugged-process-to-a-certain-file/) are explaining the technique but I would like to attach to a process which is already running remotely. I tried with WinDbg command options but that did not turn out to be solution for me. Can somebody suggest me on how to achieve this.

Comment: I wonder how much effort you put into the automation of this issue. How often do you debug? Why write some sort of user interface for this? It seems like an XY problem to me. You're trying to achieve something and it seems the wrong way to do it like this. But we can't tell, since we don't understand the whole use case. E.g. why not read pseudo-random values from disk instead? Or replace the random number generator object by a hard-coded random number generator?

Comment: @Thomas, Now I have ruled out this case and decided to disable the devices which caused the timeout. You can refer to the discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31378816/data-input-to-debugger-before-hitting-the-breakpoint/31386173?noredirect=1#comment51034791_31386173).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Pseudo code above does not convey your intent.

I am not sure why you require a kernel debugging connection to remote debug an executable **(reference the link in your query)**

if you want to debug an executable running in a remote machine that you can connect to use remote debugging connection session.

a sample setup enumerated below debugs calc.exe running in a remote machine using remote debugging session

Host-----------------physical machine  xp sp3 32 bit
target---------------virtual machine   xp sp3 32 bit
network--------------Loop back Adapter

```
C:\>net view | grep -i xp & echo kd wont connect target not booted with /DEBUG
\\XPSP3VM
kd wont connect target not booted with /DEBUG

C:\>kd -k com:pipe,port=\\.\pipe\debugPipe,resets=0,reconnect
Opened \\.\pipe\debugPipe
Waiting to reconnect...
^B   <---------force exit
"lets run windbg -server npipe:pipe=\\.\pipe\debugPipe -v calc.exe 
in the target machine and connect to it with cdb -server:xxxx from host

C:\>cdb -remote npipe:server=xpsp3vm,pipe=\\.\pipe\debugPipe
Connected to server with 'npipe:server=xpsp3vm,pipe=\\.\pipe\debugPipe'

CommandLine: calc.exe  (mapped shared folder in host)
Symbol search path is: srv*z:\*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols

7c90120e cc              int     3
\Admin (npipe \\.\pipe\debugPipe) connected at Wed Jul 22 11:49:41 2015
0:000> .echo "yay we are remote debucking now"
yay we are remote debucking now
0:000> lm m calc*
start    end        module name
01000000 0101f000   calc       (deferred)
.clients
\Admin (npipe \\.\pipe\debugPipe), last active Wed Jul 22 11:54:19 2015
HostMachine\HostUser, last active Wed Jul 22 11:44:06 2015
0:000> kb
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child
0007fb1c 7c9402ed 7ffde000 7ffdf000 00000000 ntdll!DbgBreakPoint
0007fc94 7c91fad7 0007fd30 7c900000 0007fce0 ntdll!LdrpInitializeProcess+0x1014
0007fd1c 7c90e457 0007fd30 7c900000 00000000 ntdll!_LdrpInitialize+0x183
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ntdll!KiUserApcDispatcher+0x7
0:000> .echo "only echo is echoed all other aw are dumped here"
only echo is echoed all other aw are dumped here
```

a screenshot added in case what is written sounds gibberish[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information and I use tcp for the communication instead of pipe. I run `dbgsrv.exe -t tcp:port=1234` on a remote machine, and from my desktop I attach to the process which is already running on the remote machine using `windbg -premote
tcp:port=1234,host=<ServerName> -pn myapp.exe`.

Comment: well whatever that rocks your boat should be fine if you think you found an answer from what is posted above accept it so that it floats on top and some wayfarers can see the beam from the beacon